# Regex to validate day and Month of a given day in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write a regex expressions in PHP to validate two variables:

1). $months range from (1 - 31)

2). $days range from (1 - 12)

How could you write that regex expression for each ?

Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions for checking number ranges is a bad idea.  Your best bet is to cast the value *as a number* then use an `if` statement to validate it.

Comment: In addition to all the other answers, that are telling you the smart way to take care of this (using logic available in PHP)..check out [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637637/regex-for-checking-if-number-is-less-or-greater-than/23637810#23637810) as to why its not easy to evaluate ranges in regex.

Comment: Well this is interesting. Do you need exact validation (the given date exists with certainty) or just rough validation? With rough validation I mean that is it okay that some individual dates get passed as false positives?

Comment: You might could do it like they do here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578628/is-there-a-regular-expression-for-a-comma-separated-list-of-discrete-values by listing every day of the month with the `|` operator, but what a hassle.

Comment: Since when are there 31 months in a year, or only 12 days in a month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using simple php opperators,e.g.

```
if( $months > 0 && $months < 32 )
```

But the issue you will have is some months only have some many days. Use this instead:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php